# What advantages are there to working in the non-profit sector?

Tags: non-profit

Are there advantages to working for a non-profit tech company?

As in working on site full time for a non-profit organization like an NGO, or charitable cause, like [COWOBO](http://cowobo.org/).

Also, if there are what are they? What type of challenges are there: Resources, funding, etc?

What are some of the biggest challenges that exist?

Comment: Hi chrisjlee - your question was closed because it is quite broad and is asking for a poll or extended discussion; StackExchange strives for practical, answerable questions.  If you would like guidance for writing a specific, answerable question about a problem you are facing, please feel free to ask in [meta] or [chat].  Thanks!

Comment: Also, please don't cross post - this is certainly on-topic, but as jcmeloni mentioned, too broad.

Comment: It really depends.  some non-profits are HUGE corporations, while others will be almost corner-store size.  the huge ones are generally funded in large part by the governmnet/have special tax and purchasing discounts.  so, this means that they'll tend to have alot of money to put into the office, into programs for employees, and for exploring new technologies/techniques.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, a tour with a reasonably impressive nonprof can form the foundation of an entire career. Granted, the financial compensation often leaves much to be desired, but the investment pays off in spades when prospective for-profit employers see that name on your resume / portfolio. Participation in a worthy cause sends a very positive message about a candidate as a person.

This has been my experience. I was fortunate enough to have done a six-month project for a very well-known, high-visibility and pretty universally popular nonprof early in my career. Since then, I haven't gone a week without at least one headhunter soliciting new opportunities; at least half the projects I've worked on since then picked me up expressly because of that experience.

HTH :)

Comment: wow, only just now saw this answer.  and saying that the 'financial compensation often leaves much to be desired' is false.  yes, a lot of non-profs are small and poorly funded, but there are plenty that are massive, nation-wide corporations.  they have quite a bit of revenue, and channel all that back into the office(s) and the workers.

Comment: @acolyte - I should have been more clear. I meant, "the financial compensation often leaves much to be desired" *as an intern, which was my experience. I meant to present a career-building context. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ah, i see.  that makes a bit more sense then.